# Increasing font/typeface size in Windows Live Mail (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-live-mail, font-faces

I am a handicapped user. As my handicap progresses, I find the font/typeface size used in the read panel is progressively harder to read. I already have the font size set to "largest". Is there a way to increase the size of the font/typeface used in the read panel?

Answer (score 1):

Before I tell you how to change all your settings, You need to know about 1 trick, that works in the browser (usually) and In the Live e-mail programs. ZOOMING.
**Hold down the CTRL button and press the + & - Keys on the keyboard or number pad.**
This method could be superior to making any other changes, it is fast, adjustable, and less things break when you use this method. 
To use that method in the e-mail , double click on an eamil to open it first.

To change the Read and compose fonts in WLM Windows live e-mail.

There is a very poorly marked blue button on the same line as the menus

[image]
Clicking on that button can get you to the Options for Mail.

---

Once you get into the options, there will be 2 tabs you will want to access.
1) Read , click on the read tab in options.
[image]
To adjust the font size for reading e-mails , select Font in that tab as shown.
Then adjust the font sizes to larger.  (see notes)

---

2) Compose, for making an e-mail on your end.
[image]
Click on Font Settings, and adjust the Mail font here in the compose tab.

Notes: This is based on Windows Live Mail 2013 version.

Some people indicate that these changes are not enough. This is becuse many of the e-mails we are observing are created in HTML, the fonts are set in the html.  Look back in the 2nd picture and you can see **[X] Read All Messages in Plain Text** This has ramifications of reading the actual HTML code items itself, but returns control of the font rendering to the settings.

When all else fails, the magnifyer has 2 methods of operation, zooming the whole screen >200%, and being used to zoom up parts of the screen. Refer to the Help in the magnifyer, or ask about it in another question.

Comment: Ctrl-+ didn't zoom for me but Ctrl+ scrolling the mouse wheel did. Works great on HTML.